RefinableDate managed property for a calculated column is empty
I have this calculated column named "PUETADateTime" which sum up the value for other calculated columns as follow:-

now inside Search service >> I edit a Refinable Date and linked to the related managed property as follow:-

but when i am viewing this refinable inside my search web part i will get empty values,

although this calculated column have values inside sharepoint lists.. and i submit a re-index for the site around 30 hours.
Any advice?
Regards
